# Getting an error while getting the value of a label in js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a functional food program but in options page i am trying to change the quantity but i get this error. foodoptions.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null.

This is my code for food options:

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="foodoptions.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>Choose Your Food!</header>
    <br>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="item1">
            <br>
            <p class="item">Burger</p>
            <p class="amont">Quantity:</p>
            <button class="add" onclick="add()">+</button>
            <p class="quantity">0</p>
            <button class="minus" onclick="minus()">-</button>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="item1">
            <br>
            <p class="item">Pizza</p>
            <p class="amont">Quantity:</p>
            <button class="add" onclick="add()">+</button>
            <p class="quantity">0</p>
            <button class="minus" onclick="minus()">-</button>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="item1">
            <br>
            <p class="item">Garlic Bread</p>
            <p class="amont">Quantity:</p>
            <button class="add" onclick="add()">+</button>
            <p class="quantity">0</p>
            <button class="minus" onclick="minus()">-</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="foodoptions.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
body{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(110, 81, 81, 0.726);
}

header{
    background-color: mediumblue;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
}

.container p,div{
    color: white;
}

button{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

.amont.add,.quantity{
    display: inline;
}

.amont{
    display: inline;
    
}

.item{
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-right: 70px;
    /* background-color: white; */
    /* color: black; */
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.item1{
    background-color: rgb(219, 172, 43);
    width: 250px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 1000px;
    height: 150px;
    align-items: bottom;
}
```

js:

```
quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").innerHTML;

function add(){
    console.log(quantity)
}
```

My js code is small for now but will increase later, anyway I hope some of you can try to help me. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: cannot see any element with id quantity.

Comment: There are several elements with `class="quantity"` but no `id="quantity"`. What element are you trying to print?

Comment: The question title mentions a label, but I don't see any `<label>` elements.

Comment: `getElementById("quantity")` function finds an element with attribute `id="quantity"`, Your snippet does not have any element with id quantity, so it returns `null` hence the error states Cannot read property innterHTML of Null

Comment: thanks. It works now. I was trying to simplify it earlier but forgot to make it id right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementById` returns element that match the ID attribute of the text you specified.
If there is no element with the same ID, nothing wil return.

To fix your issue you need to add an ID attribute, and than the method will work.

for example:
<div **id="elementID"** class="divClass">

You can have more reading [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp)

In addition, id recommend to check out the `querySelector` method that let you select element by their ID, class, type ect, you can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)